# Please help me to identify the pattern

Tags: calculation-puzzle, missing-digits

[image]
$(A)72$

$(B)18$

$(C)9$

$(D)19$

Source:My coaching DPP

The question asks you identify the pattern and find the missing character.

I have been trying to solve this problem from a long time but I have not found any pattern till now. Please help!!

Comment: Hi Divya, don't forget to state in the puzzle where you got this from - otherwise your question might end up being closed due to not having the correct attribution (it's part of PSE's anti-plagiarism policy). Is it another coaching DPP like your last puzzle? If so, do state it in the text (if not, state where it *is* from instead...). Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this one is another mistyped question, the answer is 16 (three numbers added minus the lower number) :P

Comment: This question is not wrong. Yes, 16 makes a pattern but the correct answer is one of the numbers given in options.

Answer (score 3):

Since:

> 15+3=18
>  7+9+2=18
>
>  and
>
>  26+18=44
>  25+8+11=44

Then:

> **16**+4=20
>  5+9+6=20

So the number is:

> 16

Comment: Simpler put, 2+9+7-3 = 15, 11+8+25-18 = 26 => 9+6+5-4 = 16

Comment: So, is it A, B, C or D?  :-(

Comment: @FlorianF Good point!

Comment: it is A+B+C= center+D= clockwise A=2 is 9 oclock 2+9+7=18 15+3=18

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a typo

Given that there are only 2 examples to work with, it must be a very simple formula.  Usually the formula uses each number once.

I wrote a computer search for all ways to combine the 4 numbers around the circle with operations +, -, *, / in a way that it produces the value in the circle for the left and right case.  The only formulas that came out are: (N + E + W - S) and (N + E + |W - S|), with many variations (permutations of the terms, various placement of brackets).  These evaluate to respectively 16 and 6 for the middle case.

But these don't appear in the choices.

So either the formula is unusually complicated or there is a typo.  I believe the second option is more likely.

Answer (score -1):

It's:

> 9 (C). The formula is $|top-base|+|left-right|+k$, where $k=4,3,2$.

Comment: If you vote to close a question, please don't also answer it.